# Increment current Date by two days

Tags: java

I want to increment todays date (Present date) by 2 days because I need to use it to be sending reminders two days before an appointment.

Comment: have a look at the calendar class: grab one and increment the day field

Comment: See the javadoc for Calendar [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Please note that using `Calendar` or the JDK `Date` class will _also_ include **time**, which may cause problems if not accounted for.  They also have an attached timezone, which may cause it's own problems.  Some further requirements may help us give better advice.

Comment: If you are doing a significant amount of work with Dates then see also [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which is a replacement for the Java Date and time classes and is easier to use.

Comment: Now *Joda-Time* has been supplanted by its successor, the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 9):

Use `java.util.Calendar`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // starts with today's date and time
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);  // advances day by 2
Date date = c.getTime(); // gets modified time
```

As of jdk8 you can use

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use this to send reminders two days **before** the event, won't you need a date object 2 days prior to your date Object?

Anyways, assuming you have your Date object as Date you can get a date object two days after that date by adding 2*24*60*60*1000 milliseconds to it, in which add up to 48 hour.

`java.util.Date newDt = new Date(dt.getTime() + 2*24*60*60*1000);`

But I would recommend you take a look at the Calendar api..
Here's what you'll need in that case. [Calendar.add() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Two days does not always equal 48 hours, it also could be 47 or 49 (begin / end of daylight saving time)

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, also, leap seconds are not taken into account and various other weird datetime features...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code if you want a specific format

```
String date = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-YYYY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) api.  It provides all the tools you need.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest solution is:

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400 * 1000 * 2)
```

would give you date object 48 hours ahead from now

Comment: Two days does not always equal 48 hours, it also could be 47 or 49 (begin / end of daylight saving time)

Comment: @Arjan - Agreed, assuming that a day is always 24 hours is quite hazardous.

Comment: new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (86400*2))